# How to play disabled embeded youtube videos in android app?

Tags: android, youtube

We have multiple youtube channels under one CMS. We also disabled videos for embedding to other websites. Now we have created one android app, but the embedded video is not playing. Can someone explain how to do it? and how to allow embedded videos to android app?